# combining boolean results from two columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following example data from two Boolean columns:

```
ID      Male      Female
1        1          0
2        0          1
3        0          1
4        1          0
5        0          1
```

I would like to combine the two columns into a single column containing just 'M' and 'F'. Also, I would preferably like to do it in the SELECT statement I am writing while defining the column.

The result then should be something like:

```
ID     Gender
1        M
2        F
3        F
4        M
5        F
```

I know I could achieve this with separate update statements like:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET Gender='M'
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE t2.Male=1
```

and

```
UPDATE table_1
SET Gender='F'
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE t2.Female=1
```

But I was really hoping to achieve the same result while declaring the Gender column?

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Male = 1 THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END AS Gender`

Comment: what if they are both 0?  or 1?

Comment: FWIW, sql server does not have a true boolean type. We have the bit datatype which is often used like a boolean but it can have 3 values. NULL, 0, 1

Comment: @Hogan I guess that means they are transgender. :D

Comment: @SeanLange So a "T" or "X"?

Comment: I ended up using a combination of @Ullas / @Juan and @kbball. As you mentioned, in this case it was probably prudent to allow for `NULL` (both 0 or 1), hence using `CASE` instead of `IIF`.

Thank you again for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_1
SET Gender= CASE WHEN Male = 1 THEN 'M'
                 WHEN Female = 1 THEN 'F'
                 ELSE 'Other' // optional
            END;
```

Of course im trying to be open mind and guess you allow `Male = 0 and Female = 0`
otherwise you can simplify with **[IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)**

```
UPDATE table_1
SET Gender = IIF ( Male = 1, 'M', 'F' );
```

Comment: I believe we need 'ELSE' too :) The world has changed

Comment: @techspider Yes I know that is why I use `CASE`, but OP didnt define any value so on this case is `NULL` but I will include it as optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Gender = (
    CASE WHEN t2.Male = 1 AND t2.Female = 0 THEN 'M'
    WHEN t2.Male = 0 AND t2.Female = 1 THEN 'F'
    ELSE NULL END
)
FROM Table_1 t1
JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: why need  `JOIN` ?

Comment: Male and Female columns are in Table_2 and need to update Table_1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN Male = 1 THEN 'M'
ELSE 'F' END AS gender
FROM My_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `select if(Male = 1, 'M', 'F') as gender`?